# zf2 change error code returned by Callback validator

Tags: php, validation, callback, zend-framework2, error-code

I successfully use the [ZF2 `Callback` validator](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.validator.callback.html) but I have a problem with the code that it returns. Here the config that use:

```
'validators'=>array(
    array(
        'name' => 'Callback',
        'options' => array(
            'messages'=>array(
                Callback::INVALID_VALUE => 'Error',
            ),
            'callback' => function ($value,$context=array()) {
                if(empty($value) && empty($context['company'])){
                    $isValid = false;
                }else{
                    $isValid = true;
                }
                return $isValid;
            },
        )
    )
),
```

The problem is in the error code which returns no message

It returns `callbackValue` which is the value of the constant `INVALID_VALUE` of the `Callback` validation class

Is there a way to change this value through the options?

I would like to avoid writing a custom class for each item that I have to validate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried but this code works totally fine:

```
use Zend\Validator\Callback;

.....

array(
    'name' => 'Callback',
    'options' => array(
        'messages' => array(
            Callback::INVALID_VALUE => 'My custom message',
            Callback::INVALID_CALLBACK => 'My custom message'
        ),
        'callback' => function(){
                return false;
            }
    )
)
```

The key of the message is: `callbackValue` but the message I get is `'My custom message'`

Comment: as I wrote I have the need to have a different key , not the message

Comment: @ciro - That is not possible. You would have to make your own Validator to be able to customize the names of the keys.

Comment: @ciro You wrote it ?

Comment: @Stephane if I wrote that comment probably wrote the validator customized

Answer (score 0):

in your form class, within your callback function get the form field and set a custom error for it:

```
...
'callback' => function(){
   ...
   // validation logic returns 
   // one of the possible messages into $message

   $this->getInputFilter()
        ->get('<FieldName>')
        ->setErrorMessage($message);

   return false;
}
```